# WP7 - MessageBox that automaticly disappear

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I need inform user about deleting item I want show message like this: "Item was deleted". This message shows and after 3 seconds automaticly dispear. But I can solve it with MessageBox because it have buttons and i dont want to show any button in that message box. Next I ned to solve how can I automaticly hide that message after few seconds.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use a `Popup` control to replace the message box, then use a `DispatcherTimer` (or a thread) to close it after a few seconds). But if it's just to display a notification, you should consider using the `ToastPrompt` from the coding4fun toolkit. It mimics the Windows Phone native notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own form that looks like a message box with a timer, display the form for however many seconds you want it to display and then close it.